# How do I create an "if" statement to evaluate the first 7 characters in PHP?

Tags: php, substr

I'm trying to achieve writing this in php:

```
if ($image starts with "photos/") {
echo "the image path starts with photos/";
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if (substr($image, 0, 7) == 'photos/')
```

Comment: thanks logan serman . this answer is good , but i think this code is benefit too,  
`substr(string str,int start,[int length]);`

Comment: @Andi... Considering looking at http://us2.php.net/substr to see more options available to you when you use substr.